# add condition to collection join

Tags: magento-1.9, select, order-grid

```
$collection = $observer->getOrderGridCollection();

//get the attribute id of our custom eav
$attributeId = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute')
    ->getIdByCode('catalog_product', 'custom_attribute');

$select = $collection->getSelect();
//join eav value to order grid
$select->join('catalog_product_entity_int', '`catalog_product_entity_int`.entity_id=`main_table`.entity_id AND `catalog_product_entity_int`.attribute_id = ' . $attributeId,
    array('custom' => 'value'));
```

I want to add a yes/no column to sales order grid,

base on whether the order contains product that has custom attribute > certain number value

I currently have above observer for `salesOrderGridCollectionLoadBefore`, but it only display custom attribute value of first product,

how do I accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
array('custom' => new Zend_Db_Expr('max(`catalog_product_entity_int`.value) > ' . $configValue, 'yes', 'no'))
```

figured out myself, fixed by adding a zend db expression with condition